# Verifying zsh version on macOS Catalina upon brew install

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh

The default zsh version located at `/bin/zsh` is `5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`.

I brew installed a new version, added `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells`, and issued `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh` to change it to that one - it's output: `chsh: no changes made`. I've also tried issuing `sudo dscl . -create /Users/$USER UserShell /usr/local/bin/zsh` and still see, upon restarting the command line and the machine itself, `which zsh` and `type zsh` showing `/bin/zsh`.

I checked System Preferences -> unlock -> right click my user and click Advanced Options -> and I see `/usr/local/bin/zsh` for Login shell.

On command line:

- `which zsh` outputs `/bin/zsh`
- `echo $0` outputs `-zsh`
- `ps -o comm= $$` outputs `-zsh`
- `echo $SHELL` outputs `/usr/local/bin/zsh`
- `type zsh` outputs `zsh is /bin/zsh`
- `/usr/local/bin/zsh --version` outputs `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)`
- `zsh --version` outputs `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`

I'm wondering, how can I ensure version 5.8 is being used?

Could it be that because `/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` in my PATH, that `/bin/zsh` is resolved instead of `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, assuming shell binary is also resolved using PATH?

Comment: *"Could it be that because /bin is before /usr/local/bin in my PATH, that /bin/zsh is resolved instead of /usr/local/bin/zsh, assuming shell binary is also resolved using PATH?"* - **Yes**, just tested in a Catalina VM

Comment: Great, thanks for quick confirmation. I'm afraid of switching the order on the PATH because of version issues that may arise. I could try and see what breaks. I'm wondering if there's another way to only get /usr/local/bin/zsh resolved while leaving /bin before /usr/local/bin. I wonder if that's to explicitly add that binary on the path. I see a similar issue with vi - https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/how-do-i-run-homebrew-vi-on-macos-instead-of-the-older-version-apple-provided/11059#11059. Homebrew has a custom flag for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH evaluation command in /etc/zprofile probably overrides your shell settings in the Directory Services.

If you give priority to /bin in the global PATH (or even in the user's .zprofile/.zshrc/...) Apple's zsh will be your default shell exec despite other settings in your user ds profile.

---

If you want to keep your current PATH settings (prioritize /bin) you can move/copy brew's zsh link to a (new) dir like /usr/local/zsh/bin/.

Then change the shell dir and the shell with `sudo nano /etc/shells` and `chsh -s /usr/local/zsh/bin/zsh` and finally change your PATH in .zprofile/.zshrc to

```
export PATH="/usr/local/zsh/bin:$PATH"
```

You have to renew the zsh link in /usr/local/zsh/bin/ after updating/upgrading brew's zsh!

Comment: I'm questioning this - "You have to renew the zsh link in /usr/local/zsh/bin/ after updating/upgrading brew's zsh!" because when I do ls -la in /usr/local/zsh/bin I see:  zsh -> /usr/local/bin/zsh, which itself is a link to ../Cellar/zsh/5.8/bin/zsh-5.8. So, I'm thinking that upgrading with brew, I wouldn't have to update the second link.

Comment: @sugarcane After an update/upgrade of zsh the link still contains the path to ../Cellar/zsh/5.8/bin/zsh-5.8 while the real path will be e.g. ../Cellar/zsh/5.8.1/bin/zsh-5.8.1.

Comment: Yes, I see it - when I do this (full path): readlink /usr/local/bin/zsh, I get: ../Cellar/zsh/5.8/bin/zsh.

Questioning this all, as I may forget to update the 2nd link upon brew update, unless I do scheduling or scripting to keep it up to date, as macOS updates may update this, or alternatively I could move up /usr/local/bin in path, as brew suggests. There's a security issue with that suggestion, albeit one that's considered "bikeshedding": https://discourse.brew.sh/t/is-it-dangerous-to-have-usr-local-bin-ahead-of-usr-bin-in-your-path/6097.

Comment: @sugarcane I don't really advocate my solution (and implemented it in my VM only to test the whole scenario) but the OP explicitly requested it: *" I'm afraid of switching the order on the PATH because of version issues that may arise. I could try and see what breaks. I'm wondering if there's another way to only get /usr/local/bin/zsh resolved while leaving /bin before /usr/local/bin. I wonder if that's to explicitly add that binary on the path. I see a similar issue with vi..."* (see the OP's comment in the question.